# not able to use distinct and sort in same query whereas able to run it in shell - mongo

Tags: mongodb-query

I'm able to run distinct and sort in the same query  in shell. But when I try using pymongo I got the following error,

*TypeError: distinct() takes at most 3 arguments (4 given)*

Answer (score 0):

In older versions of Mongo you used to have an ability to use sort + distinct like that:

```
db.collection.distinct("date").sort({date:1})
```

But for now there is no such possibility, cause result of "distinct" command is document, but "sort" function can be only called on cursor https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/cursor.sort/

Comment: not like cursor method, I able to do like *>db.collection.distinct("date", {'$sort':{'date':1}})*